# TFS Permanently Merging Two Files (how to track?)

Tags: tfs, merge

I have two files, `A.cs` and `B.cs`, next to each other in the same branch. I want to copy/paste `B.cs` into `A.cs` such that `A.cs` contains its original contents as well as the contents of `B.cs`.

In TFS, this means a delete operation on `B.cs`, and an edit operation on `A.cs`. However, we lose the revision history of `B.cs`. Is there a way to tell TFS that `B.cs` is now `A.cs`?

Is this a use case for a baseless merge?

```
tf merge /baseless B.cs A.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case you can pend a baseless merge with `B.cs` as the target and `A.cs` as the source, then pend a delete on `B.cs`.

In this case, you will then have the history for `B.cs` accessible when viewing the history for `A.cs`:

[image: File History After Baseless Merge + Delete]

Comment: This won't work if `A.cs` already exists. Remember, I'm merging the two files. According to the `tf rename` help: "You cannot rename an item if: ... The new name already exists in the Team Foundation source control server and is not a folder."

Comment: I see now what you're trying to accomplish.  Sorry, I didn't understand your question completely.  Clever approach, by the way, which I think will work out to your liking.

Comment: My confusion came about because I read "copy/paste into `A.cs`" as if one would replace the contents of `A.cs` and `B.cs`, not create a composite of `A.cs` and `B.cs`.  I edited your question to clarify.  Of course feel free to edit my edit if you would prefer.